# Finding active IPv6 interfaces under Mac OS (using Python)

Tags: python, linux, macos, ipv6

My objective is to write a Python script that provides the user with a series of link-local IPv6 addresses of specific devices.   My technique is to send out a multicast ping and then use neighbor discovery to get a list of addresses which I can then filter down.

The first step is this:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['ping6', '-c', '2', 'ff02::1%en0'])
```

The problem is the term **en0** at the end.   It is not a constant.   On MacOS it is **en0** but on Linux it will be **eth0** or possibly **br0**.   Windows has a different command but the same problem.   Without the interface qualifier the **ping6** command does not work.

Also, some systems may have multiple interfaces.

So how would a Python script get a list of those interfaces?

Alternatively, can this be done by using the **socket** package and not **subprocess**?   (I don't want my script to require privileged mode and using **ping** gets around that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux there's no guarantee that your first Ethernet interface will be named `eth0`.  It might be named `p1s3` or `em1` or even `internal`.  Or `bob`.

Under both Linux and OS X you can use the `netifaces` python module to get a list of available interfaces *and* addresses associated with those interfaces.  For example, consider the following code:

```
import netifaces

for iface in netifaces.interfaces():
    addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(iface)
    for addr in addrs.get(netifaces.AF_INET6, []):
        print '%-8s %s' % (iface, addr['addr'])
```

Which on my Linux system produces:

```
lo       ::1
enp0s25  fe80::3e97:eff:febf:6dce%enp0s25
docker0  fe80::d8d1:31ff:feb2:b6c6%docker0
br-ext   fe80::f879:f3ff:fe6b:f445%br-ext
lxcbr0   fe80::fc45:6bff:fefd:543%lxcbr0
vethf8c98b2 fe80::a0a7:3bff:feff:4f9b%vethf8c98b2
vnet0    fe80::fc54:ff:fee5:2818%vnet0
```

And on my OS X system produces:

```
lo0      ::1
lo0      fe80::1%lo0
en3      fe80::e2f8:47ff:fe41:866a%en3
```

I have no idea if this works under Windows or not.

Comment: Wow this looks pretty good.   I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know how it works out.   I was afraid I would have to resort to parsing the output of netstat or something.

Comment: This looks to be the best solution I have found for MacOS and Linux at least.   Under Windows the Interfaces are represented by UUID strings which, I suppose, can be translated somehow into the interface index that Windows uses.